# Does it make sense to say "to be cross over something" with cross meaing annoyed?

Tags: verbs, prepositions, emotions

We can say someone is mad/angry/annoyed over something. Can we use the same structure for the adjective "cross"?

Comment: Yes, probably, but it’s usually “cross about” something.

Comment: This usage of “cross” is very British; Americans don’t typically use “cross” this way (we prefer more emphatic synonyms: *pissed*, *ticked off*). It’s not totally unheard of, but it’s not common either.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, according to [https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/cross_3#:~:text=cross](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/cross_3#:%7E:text=cross)

**​cross** (with somebody): annoyed or quite angry

I was cross with him for being late.

Please don't get cross. Let me explain.

Comment: Thanks. Would you say the preposition "over" following "cross" sounds natural?

Comment: As an English speaker, using the word "over" sounds unusual, but not necessarily wrong. Crossover usually means a hybrid between two things or it means going from one place to another. A "crossover episode" is a TV show that has characters from two different shows. A crossover vehicle is something between a car and a light truck.